# Get a random list item in Haskell

Tags: haskell

After [reviewing this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416365/generate-a-random-integer-in-a-range-in-haskell) I am trying to use the random number generator to return a random list item based on the return of the `randomIO` generator.

Full Code:

```
module Randomizer where
import System.IO
import System.Random

data Action = Create | Destroy
  deriving (Enum, Eq, Show)

type History = [Action]

-- | this looks at three sets of histories, and returns an appropriate Action
type ThreeHistoryDecisionMaker = History -> History -> History -> Action

allThreeDecisionMakers :: [ThreeHistoryDecisionMaker]
allThreeDecisionMakers = [decision1, decision2, decision3, decision4, decision5]

chooseRandomDecision :: [ThreeHistoryDecisionMaker] -> Int -> Strategy3P
chooseRandomDecision = allThreeDecisionMakers !! randomIO(0,4)
```

But I get the following errors:

```
special_program1.hs:249:16:
    Couldn't match type ‘Action’
                  with ‘History -> History -> History -> Action’
    Expected type: [[ThreeHistoryDecisionMaker] -> Int -> ThreeHistoryDecisionMaker]
      Actual type: [ThreeHistoryDecisionMaker]
    In the first argument of ‘(!!)’, namely ‘allThreeDecisionMakers’
    In the expression: all3PStrategies !! randomIO (0, 4)

special_program1.hs:249:35:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘(t0, t1) -> Int’
                with actual type ‘IO a0’
    The function ‘randomIO’ is applied to one argument,
    but its type ‘IO a0’ has none
    In the second argument of ‘(!!)’, namely ‘randomIO (0, 4)’
    In the expression: all3PStrategies !! randomIO (0, 4)
```

Why is the first error block wanting to expect a list of everything inside it?

What does the second code block mean?

Comment: The `IO` action `randomIO` does not accept an argument.  It also returns an `IO a` value, such as `IO Int`.  The types `Int` and `IO Int` are not the same, so you'll have to make `chooseRandomDecision` return an `IO something`.

Comment: You also have the type `threeHistoryDecisionMaker`, but all types must begin with a capital letter.  Is this a typo?

Comment: @bheklilr Yes,  typo, fixed

Answer (score 13):

`randomIO` is *not* a "random function". Such a thing doesn't exist in Haskell, it wouldn't be referentially transparent. Instead, as the name suggests, it's *an IO action* which can yield a random value. It makes no sense to index a list with an IO action, `!! randomIO(0,4)` isn't possible. (It's impossible also for another reason: `randomIO` creates unlimited values, you want `randomRIO` (with an R for "range parameter") if you need to specify a `(0,4)` range.)

What you need to to do to get the value *yielded* by the action: well, monads! If you haven't learned the theory about those yet, never mind. A random-indexer could look thus:

```
atRandIndex :: [a] -> IO a  -- note that this is gives itself an IO action
atRandIndex l = do
    i <- randomRIO (0, length l - 1)
    return $ l !! i
```

I suggest you actually use that function to implement your task.

But back to the code you posted... there's more problems. If you specify the type of `chooseRandomDecision` with two arguments, then you need to actually define it as a function of these arguments! But your definition doesn't accept any arguments at all, it merely uses the globally-defined list `allThreeDecisionMakers` (use of global variables never needs to be stated in the type).

Moreover, if you're choosing from a list of `THDMaker`s, then the resulting element will also have that type, what else! So unless `Strategy3P` is simply another synonym of `History -> History -> History -> Action`, this won't do as a result, even if you contain it in the right monad.

Comment: So I understand a random function doesn;t exist, but it can be achieved using seeds, or correctly specifying the "same" parameters into a function call.  So `Strategy3P` is simply a synonym/type of `History -> History -> History -> Action`

Comment: But typing just `atRandIndex all3PStrategies` in the interpreter doesn't return anything.  Im still confused, but i understand the code block.

Comment: Typing just `atRandIndex all3PStrategies` won't give you anything the interpreter can display, but only because `ThreeHistoryDecisionMaker` is a function type and thus has no `Show` instance. It _does_ actually return a value though, not shown but stored in the `it` variable. (Typing `λ> it` should give an error about no instance for `(Show (History -> History -> History -> Action))`.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61530/discussion-between-chris-frisina-and-leftaroundabout).

Answer (score 0):

This answer offers a simple, effective solution to the problem posed in the title: "Get a random list item in Haskell".

The package [Test.QuickCeck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html) provides a number of helpful, straightforward functions for generating random values (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#g:5). A function that returns random values from a list (wrapped IO) can be built by composing the QuickTest functions `elements` and `generate`:

```
import Test.QuickCheck (generate, elements)

randItem :: [a] -> IO a
randItem = generate . elements
```

chris Frisina's function `chooseRandomDecision` would then look like this:

```
chooseRandomDecision :: [ThreeHistoryDecisionMaker] -> IO ThreeHistoryDecisionMaker
chooseRandomDecision = randItem
```

The user Cale in the [#haskell channel on freenode](http://irc.lc/freenode/haskell/) helped coach me to this solution.

note: This solution works with QuickCheck 2.7.6, but needs some alteration for earlier versions. You can update to the latest version with `cabal install QuickCheck`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370465/function-variable-not-in-scope-haskell).